# ImageView over other ImageView with limitations

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have ImageView (let's call it parent) on my layout and I need create n amount of ImageView during working with app and place them over parent ImageView; also, created ImageView shouldn't go beyond parent ImageView. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to stack a few ImageViews on top of each other, like layering them?

Comment: I mean ImageViews should appear next to each other beginning from the left upper corner. Something like when I click "add" button, new ImageView appears on my screen and located next to previous

Comment: Have you checked out GridView and putting images inside? http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android

Comment: actually I've thought about this solution but the size of added ImageView can differ from previous or next and all ImageViews shouldnt have paddings from all sides like in tetris.

Comment: use gridview and in order to have images with same width and height use an adapter layout